# Why vector assignment changes the assigned vector

Tags: c++, vector, size, variable-assignment

Case 1

```
void insert(map<string, vector<int>> &y,const string &x)
{
vector<int> v=y[x];
if(!y.count(x)>0)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Case 2

```
void insert(map<string, vector<int>> &y,const string &x)
{
//vector<int> v=y[x];
if(!y.count(x)>0)
   {
   ...
  }
}
```

In the first case, the if statement is true. In the second case, the if is false. In both cases at first the size of y[x] was zero. But in the first case after assigning y[x] to v, the size of y[x] changes to 1.

How does this happen? And also how can we assign y[x] to v with out affecting y[x]?

Comment: If no key `x` exists, what do you want assigned to `v`? And can't you just move the definition of `v` inside the `if` block? If you can't, use `map::find` to determine the existence of the key.

Answer (score 2):

Because `map::operator[]` creates a key-value pair with default-constructed value if the key passed to it does not yet exist.

If you don't want that, either use `map::at` (which will throw an exception if the key does not exist, so you would have to handle that) or `map::find` (which returns an iterator to the element with that key, or `map::end` if there is no such element).